# Time Series Insights Preview - can't create boolean and string variables

Tags: azure, azure-timeseries-insights

I am writing data to TSI (through Event Hub). Some of my data is numeric (doubles), some is boolean and some is a text (string).

I wanted to create a `type` for my time series data. However, when I am to create variables, i have to choose one of the following kinds:

- numeric
- categorical
- aggregate

My boolean variabes don't fit into any of these categories, how to add them? Same goes with strings. In my case, they will not be categorical (and it seems that only `categorical` kind accepts strings), as I understand `categorical` = enum (not my case).

How do I create a model? Without a model I am not able to retrieve series or aggregates I think. Only raw events can be retrieved, which is rather limiting.

Answer (score 0):

What kinds of questions are you looking to answer with the bool data? Based on that we can recommend how to create variables so that you can query.